# UIButton textLabel with different fonts

Tags: ios, uibutton

Is there a way to have a UIButton with two different font sizes in its textLabel? Natively?

I don't want to have a UILabel on top.

Comment: Yes there is a way to do it natively.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this in interface builder. This GIF will show you how to increase the size of one section of the text and perhaps change its font.

[image]

To do this in code:

```
NSString *fullString = @"This bit's plain. This bit's bigger";
NSRange rangeOfPlainBit = [fullString rangeOfString:@"This bit's plain."];
NSRange rangeOfBigBit = [fullString rangeOfString:@"This bit's bigger"];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:fullString];
[attributedText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"My-font" size:15.0],
                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}
                        range:rangeOfPlainBit];
[attributedText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"My-font" size:25.0],
                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}
                        range:rangeOfBigBit];

[self.myButton setAttributedTitle:attributedText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: If you're using IB you should be able to select the text that you want and change it. You could pick multiple lines, separate sections of a long paragraph or individual letters. If you can't, you can try with code using an approach similar to what I've included above whereby you grab the bits of text that you want to change.

Comment: It seems that in IB only one line is displayed. However I can pick, as you said, the line I wanna change. But when I change from the Default state to Selected nothing is displayed even if I set the text and color. It must be something I'm missing in my code.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you selecting the state config to selected?

Comment: Cause I wanna have different text colors when default and when selected. I know I can do all these in code but I'm basically texting the capabilities of IB. My philosophy is the less code I write the less chances I get for bugs.

Comment: OK just so everyone knows. The Type of UIButton has to be changed to Custom! otherwise everything breaks when trying to set ConfigState.

Comment: I did this and it seems okay in storyboard, but if I run it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: This solution would lead the smaller text do not be center vertically. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 7):

**SWIFT 3**

```
 func customizeButtonFont(fullText: String, mainText: String, creditsText: String, button: UIButton) {
        let fontBig = UIFont(name:"SFUIDisplay-Medium", size: 16.0)
        let fontSmall = UIFont(name:"SFUIDisplay-Light", size: 14.0)
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullText, attributes: nil)

        let bigRange = (attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: mainText)
        let creditsRange = (attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: creditsText)
        attributedString.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: fontBig, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], range: bigRange)
        attributedString.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: fontSmall, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], range: creditsRange)

        button.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

just change the font size for the title.

swift:
button.titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(FONTSIZE)

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood. You need to use  NSAttributedString for different fonts on the same button.